# how do I download a file and then turn it into a base64 bit array?

Tags: javascript

This may seem like a silly question but here we go.

So all over the stacks I see stuff about bit arrays, but suppose I have the given link: `https://files.parsetfss.com/aa780683-47b2-4d25-96f6-aff80a7daba2/tfss-6c5ff0d3-9336-4ab3-be4a-22d8371d5093-picture.jpg`

The link listed above is an encrypted image file. I need to get the file from that location and then convert it into a base64 bitarray so I can then pass it to my decryptor.

Is there a good library for doing this? If so what is it, also. How do I download the file and then pass it? This may be kind of trivial, but until recently I have only done very basic javascript to display a message, not do download and manipulate its contents.

Comment: WTH is a "*base64 bitarray*"? You should download the file (using XHR) into a byte array (`ArrayBuffer`) and pass *that* to your "decryptor".

Comment: ahh gotcha! srry for the noobish question... thanks!